# Why are email verification and password reset tokens are so long in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

The tokens for email verification and password reset generated by WebApi's UserManager are over 200 characters long. I'd imagine a 20 char long random string would be sufficiently secure for this purpose. 
Is there a reason why tokens are so long?

Comment: For security reasons.

Comment: Probably. How are 200 char long strings really better than 20 char long strings? Guessing either is not practical.

Comment: @Evgeni info you inspect the source code you will see that the inner workings uses a security stamp to generate a hash in memory and then converts that using a `ToBase64String` which results in a very long security token. So it is basically a byte array converted to a base64 string.